# How to iterate a text string in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am not an expert in databases but I have to deal with one in a new app for Android I am just creating, which includes SQLite. I have 2 tables, let's call them *Words* and *Chars*. *Words* mainly register words the user enters, like a dictionary. *Chars* is meant to register any new single character included in the words added to the *Words* table and count the number of times any character is included in the *Words* table.

Having this scenario I decided creating a trigger to update the *Chars* table everytime a new word is added/deleted/modified in the *Words* and it seems to work as expected, my question is now, how should I iterate over any character in a newly entered word? I found that there is a FOR .. IN .. LOOP statement in SQL but as far as I can appreciate it is not available for SQLite. Any suggestion?

This is the script I created to generate from scratch the database, but it is not complete as it is not registering the times any character is appearing but just registers them. In addition, it is complaining for the "FOR" keyword in the trigger definition.

```
CREATE TABLE Words (id_word INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, meaning TEXT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE Chars (id_char INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, char TEXT UNIQUE);

CREATE TRIGGER NewWord BEFORE INSERT ON Words BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..length(NEW.meaning) LOOP
    INSERT INTO Chars (char) VALUES (SUBSTR(NEW.meaning,i,1));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an embedded database, SQLite does not have control flow statements like FOR, but expects the containing application to implement all control logic.

Unfortunately, Android's built-in SQLite API does not allow registering user-defined functions, so you will not be able to do the character updates in a trigger.

Update the `Chars` table manually from your app whenever words are inserted.

Comment: I was imagine it was not possible, as you just confirmed, and I have to implement it in the Java code for Android. But just to be sure there is no other way to do it. Thanks for your answer.